# Remove hyphens from filename with Bash

Tags: bash, shell, rename

I am trying to create a small Bash script to remove hyphens from a filename.  For example, I want to rename:

CropDamageVO-041412.mpg

to

CropDamageVO041412.mpg

I'm new to Bash, so be gentle :]  Thank you for any help

Answer (score 15):

Try this:

```
for file in $(find dirWithDashedFiles -type f -iname '*-*'); do
  mv $file ${file//-/}
done
```

That's assuming that your directories don't have dashes in the name.  That would break this.

The `${varname//regex/replacementText}` syntax is explained [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html).  Just search for substring replacement.

Also, this would break if your directories or filenames have spaces in them.  If you have spaces in your filenames, you should use this:

```
for file in *-*; do
  mv $file "${file//-/}"
done
```

This has the disadvantage of having to be run in every directory that contains files you want to change, but, like I said, it's a little more robust.

Comment: If there might be spaces in the filename, you need to double-quote $file (i.e. `mv "$file" "${file//-/}"`)

Comment: Don't parse the output of `find`, and certainly not with a `for` loop: as is, your statement breaks with spaces or glob characters in file names. If you want to stick with `find` use a more robust method, e.g., `find dirWithDashedFiles -type f -name '*-*' -exec bash -c 'mv "$f" "${f//-}"' - {} \;` (note that the trailing slash is optional when the substitution string is empty).

Answer (score 7):

```
FN=CropDamageVO-041412.mpg
mv $FN `echo $FN | sed -e 's/-//g'`
```

The backticks (``) tell bash to run the command inside them and use the output of that command in the expression. The sed part applies a regular expression to remove the hyphens from the filename.

Or to do this to all files in the current directory matching a certain pattern:

```
for i in *VO-*.mpg
do
    mv $i `echo $i | sed -e 's/-//g'`
done
```

Comment: This does have the advantage of general Posix-shell compatibility. I'm never sure if I should drink *all* of the bash kool-aid.

Comment: Indeed, that's how I got into the habit of avoiding the fancy bash-isms, to the extent that I don't really use them even now when I rarely use antique shells. Solaris and AIX have a lot to answer for...

Comment: Wow, that was a quick reply.  I should have specified that I was trying to remove the hyphens in numerous files, in the format of: [NAME]VO-[DATE].mpg

Comment: No sooner said than done. If you want to learn more about bash, http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ is a good guide, although rather dry.

Comment: So perfect!  I appreciate it so much!  You just made my job much easier

Answer (score 4):

A general solution for removing hyphens from any string:

```
$ echo "remove-all-hyphens" | tr -d '-'
removeallhyphens
$
```

Answer (score 3):

```
f=CropDamageVO-041412.mpg
echo "${f//-}"
```

or, of course,

```
mv "$f" "${f//-}"
```