# Remove hyphens from a filename in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, rename

I have thoroughly researched to find / create a script that works for what I'm trying to achieve.

I'm trying to change multiple filenames with Bash.  In this type, I'm trying to just remove the hyphen:

YachtRescueVO-041512.mpg

to

YachtRescueVO041512.mpg

but then, there are more files in the same directory. I'm trying to remove both the hyphen and date:

6CO1-041512.mpg

to

6C01.mpg

I'm pretty sure I would need a regular expression to sort through it, because there are other filenaming conventions such as 6B1A, 3TSE1, CO1, 11TSE3, TS1, etc.  I realize this would be a lengthy script.  If you have free time though, I would appreciate the help greatly.

Comment: How do you determine when to remove just the hyphen and when to remove both the hyphen and the date?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158704/remove-hyphens-from-filename-with-bash/10158742#10158742

Comment: @idoperceive You are the one who actually posted the question that I just linked.  The answer I posted on that question solves this problem exactly.  It will find all of the files with hyphens in a directory and its subdirectories and rename them all to not have hyphens.

Comment: Tim, your script worked perfectly.  The sticky part is the second half.  John described my problem concisely - I can't write a script that can differentiate between the two naming conventions.

Comment: If you can't come up with rules, then the program you write won't be able to come up with a rule either.  You have to know which files need to be handled which way, by some algorithm or heuristic.  If you look at a file name, can you tell which type of rename is required?  If so, then there is an algorithm...but you have to work out what it is and write it down.  No-one can guess for you.  It might be 'all caps means remove hyphen and date; mixed case means just remove hyphen' (ignoring the extension, of course).  But you have to know, and based on that knowledge, you can devise a mechanism.

Comment: @idoperceive I just updated my answer with an example to remove the date from all files beginning with `6C01`.  Use that as a building point to do the others.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't have time to do such a script, but I think you should have a look at the following commands :

- sed
- rename
- cut
- awk

And yes, regular expressions are a really efficient way to go, but it takes quite some time to get really efficient with the syntax...

Answer (score 1):

See [Bash parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

Suppose file name is in `var`:

`new_var = ${var%-*}${var#*-}`

This would fine for your first example. for second example:

`new_var = ${var%-*}.${var#*.}`

I can't recognize what replacements you want to do from your question.

Answer (score 1):

I already posted this in the question you asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158704/remove-hyphens-from-filename-with-bash/10158742#10158742), but in case you think this is a separate issue, this will rename every file in a directory and its subdirectories:

```
for file in $(find dirWithDashedFiles -type f -iname '*-*'); do
  mv $file ${file//-/}
done
```

All of the caveats I stated in the other post apply.

You can modify the string operation to suite your needs.  For example, after you remove all of the hyphens, you can run this to get rid of the date on files with `6C01` in the name:

```
for file in $(find dirWith6C01Files -type f -iname '6C01*'); do
  mv $file ${file%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].mpg}.mpg
done
```

[This site](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) has some information on string operations in bash that should get you started on the regexes you'll need.

*Note:* I couldn't remember/find anything to specify the exact number of characters to match, a la `[0-9]{6}` in egrep.  If anyone finds it let me know.

Comment: I appreciate your patience and help.  I can finally piece this together into something that works for my situation.  Thank you!

Comment: Awesome.  Can you choose an accepted answer for your open questions?